# Broadcasting to server using WebRTC and recording on server and screen sharing

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, broadcast

I am planning to create an app which right now in feasibility study, I found WebRTC a bit promising on what I want to achieve as it provides peer to peer audio/video communication.

1. I want the client to broadcast using WebRTC to server (to leave a video message).
2. I want to record that broadcast.
3. I also want to enable screen sharing in case of peer to peer communication. (Just want one person to see the desktop screen of other person).

Is this a valid usecase to achieve using WebRTC ? Can it be done? Further more I also found some articals related to Screen sharing I tried couple of demos but they don't work with latest version of Chrome as chrome stopped the experimental stuff about screen sharing.

I am sorry I don't have any code as of now as it is in feasibility phase. I am planning to use WebRTC + NodeJs + NoSQL db to store the metadata about each session.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements :

1.WebRTC is for peer-to-peer. Meaning you can use the server only for establishing a connection and "No Data" passes through the server.
So, If you want people to leave voice/video message on your server, then you can just give a video/audio recorder in your client to record and then stream to your servers api which can store it.
2. Answered in the above point.
3. For real time screen sharing : What exactly is the use-case? You want screen sharing like team viewer where the other user can manipulate your system? Or do you want to share a html canvas where you both can collaborate?
In the first case like team viewer, I am not very sure. But for the latter you can use [Mozilla's together.js](https://togetherjs.com/)

Comment: I just want one person to see the screen of the other person.

Comment: screen as in his desktop/mobile screen? or just the website screen (In this case your app)?

Comment: Can I have 1 peer (browser) connected to a RTCPeerConnection on server (no browser) ?

Comment: If you want realtime data transfer between client and server, the best way is to use web sockets. That way, once the socket connection is established, you will be able to send data to and from server in realtime and you can even publish the changes to other clients listening to the same socket all in realtime.